# Allow jackson polymorphic deserialization with missing deserializing property

Tags: json, objectmapper

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "superClassProperty",
    "schemaVersion"
})
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "schemaVersion")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SubClassV1.class, name = "1.0"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SubClassV2.class, name = "2.0"),
})
public class SuperClass {
    @JsonProperty("superClassProperty")
    private String superClassProperty;
    @JsonProperty("schemaVersion")
    private String schemaVersion = "1.0";

    @JsonProperty("superClassProperty")
    public String getSuperClassProperty() {
        return superClassProperty;
    }
    @JsonProperty("superClassProperty")
    public void setSuperClassProperty(String superClassProperty) {
        this.superClassProperty = superClassProperty;
    }

    @JsonProperty("schemaVersion")
    public String getSchemaVersion() {
        return schemaVersion;
    }

    @JsonProperty("schemaVersion")
    public void setSchemaVersion(String schemaVersion) {
        this.schemaVersion = schemaVersion;
    }   
}

public class SubClassV1 extends SuperClass {

    @JsonProperty("property1")
    private String property1;

    @JsonProperty("property1")
    public String getProperty1() {
        return this.property1;
    }

    @JsonProperty("property1")
    public void setProperty1(String var1) {
        this.property1 = var1;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this);
    }
}

public class SubClassV1 extends SuperClass {

    @JsonProperty("property2")
    private String property2;

    @JsonProperty("property2")
    public String getProperty2() {
        return this.property2;
    }

    @JsonProperty("property2")
    public void setProperty2(String var2) {
        this.property2 = var2;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this);
    }
}
```

My JSON string is :

```
{
    "superClassProperty":"testValue",
    "property1":"property1"
}
```

What I want to achieve is to be able to deserialize to SubClassV1 by default when schemaVersion is not provided in the JSON but I keep getting the following error even when I initialize schemaVersion to "1.0" in SuperClass:

*com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unexpected token (END_OBJECT), expected FIELD_NAME: missing property 'schemaVersion' that is to contain type id  (for class experiments.SuperClass)*

Is there any way to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems Like I could use [defaultImpl](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.html#defaultImpl()) property of JsonTypeInfo.